# installation RoboEarth packages

Tags: rosinstall, roboearth, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, In this link http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth
i try to install roboearth packages  re_comm ,re_kinect_object_detector,....etc  in my fuerte

i begin by typing command :

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall
```

it begin ti install normally
then i begin typing command :

```
$ rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/fuerte 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall'
```

it appear

```
rosinstall operating on /home/salma/ros from specifications in rosinstall files  /opt/ros/fuerte, http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall
(Over-)Writing /home/salma/ros/.rosinstall
rosinstall update complete.


Now, type 'source /home/salma/ros/setup.bash' to set up your environment.
Add that to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc to set it up every time.

If you are not using bash please see http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall/NonBashShells 
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ [sudo] password for salma: 
[sudo]: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ Reading package lists... Done
Reading: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ Building dependency tree       
Building: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ Reading state information... Done
Reading: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ The following extra packages will be installed:
No command 'The' found, did you mean:
 Command 'the' from package 'the' (universe)
The: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$   bzr git git-core git-man liberror-perl mercurial mercurial-common
bzr: ERROR: unknown command "git"
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$   python-bzrlib python-configobj python-vcstools
python-bzrlib: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ Suggested packages:
Suggested: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$   bzr-doc bzr-gtk bzr-svn python-bzrlib.tests bzrtools git-daemon-run
bzr-doc: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$   git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-arch git-cvs git-svn git-email
git-daemon-sysvinit: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$   git-gui gitk gitweb qct vim emacs kdiff3 tkdiff meld xxdiff python-mysqldb
git-gui: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$   python-kerberos python-gpgme python-bzrlib-dbg
python-kerberos: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ The following NEW packages will be installed:
No command 'The' found, did you mean:
 Command 'the' from package 'the' (universe)
The: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$   bzr git git-core git-man liberror-perl mercurial mercurial-common
bzr: ERROR: unknown command "git"
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$   python-bzrlib python-configobj python-rosinstall python-vcstools
python-bzrlib: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ 0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 143 not upgraded.
0: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ Need to get 10.7 MB of archives.
No command 'Need' found, did you mean:
 Command 'seed' from package 'seed' (universe)
Need: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ After this operation, 32.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
After: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Do: command not found
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ Get:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main python-vcstools all 0.1.22-1 [20.0 kB]
Get:1: command not found
```

then the stack become in my Home not in my ROS/furete/stacks to deal with !

---

```
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ ls ~/ros
pkgs  setup.bash  setup.sh  setup.zsh  stacks
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45679/installation-roboearth-packages/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-10-12**:
salma if you check the errors, you do not have git installed (probably bzr is also not installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to run

```
source ~/ros/setup.bash
```

in the same terminal before running rosmake roboearth.
It is not clear whether you did so. If this still fails, paste the result of

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

into your question, please.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-10-12**:
it doesn't work

the result of echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH  is : /opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-12**:
This indicates that sourcing setup.bash did not work correctly. Did you get any error messages, either in the rosinstall command or when executing the source command?

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-10-12**:
now when i write
$ source ~/ros/setup.bash
bash: /home/salma/ros/setup.bash: No such file or directory

i found :
bash: /home/salma/ros/setup.bash: No such file or directory

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-12**:
Did the rosinstall command throw an errror?

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-10-12**:
no
and stack installed but in Home

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-12**:
Can you please **edit** your original question and add the exact output of the command? See http://ros.org/wiki/Support Something seems to be messed up in your system and we need to find out what. Also, what's the output of `ls ~/ros`?

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-10-12**:
ok i did :)

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-12**:
I cannot see the output of `ls ~/ros`.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-10-12**:
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ ls ~/ros
pkgs  setup.bash  setup.sh  setup.zsh  stacks

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-10-12**:
edited , the last line

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-12**:
Then the command `source ~/ros/setup.bash` definitely must work and must not throw an error.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-10-12**:
so ?? :((
it throw an error :

bash: /home/salma/ros/setup.bash: Permission denied

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-12**:
I think you must have made a mistake somewhere. Did you maybe execute the rosinstall command using sudo at some point? I suggest that you delete the complete directory `~/ros` if you don't have anything important in it (`sudo rm -rf ~/ros`) and try the rosinstall command and the source command again

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-10-12**:
Ok i will .. Thanks Lorenz